# import packages in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm trying to import a package inside an old coffe script file:

`import Quill from 'quill/core'`

But keep getting the error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

I set `type: module` inside the package.json file too. The import also is working in Vue files.

Comment: No it doesn't that's why I asked a new question.

Comment: If the other question doesn't help. could you give some more info? What version of coffeescript and node are you using? Any transpilers? Could you make a minimal coffee file to reproduce the error? Including how the coffee file is loaded into your project?

Comment: @caffeinated.tech I gladly got it solved. Including packages ain't supported in the old project. I had to manually include the code. But thanks!